# Deploy Airflow with Helm Chart, pods stuck on "wait-for-airflow-migration"

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I am trying to deploy airflow based on this helm chart version:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-7-stable/chart/Chart.yaml

Also following this production guide, I'd like to use AWS RDS PostgresSql as the external DB to store metadata:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/1.11.0/production-guide.html

I modified the metadataConnection from value.yaml with required credentials associated with the Postgresql in RDS

```yaml
  # Otherwise pass connection values in
  metadataConnection:
    user: <db-user>
    pass: <db-password>
    protocol: postgresql
    host: <db-host-name>
    port: 5432
    db: postgres
    sslmode: disable
```

However, all airflow pods are crashed due to no response on the db migration.

```bash
[2024-03-12T07:15:21.124+0000] {db.py:798} INFO - Waiting for migrations... 59 second(s)Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>    sys.exit(main())  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 59, in main    args.func(args)  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command    return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/providers_configuration_loader.py", line 55, in wrapped_function    return func(*args, **kwargs)  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 186, in check_migrations    db.check_migrations(timeout=args.migration_wait_timeout)  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 799, in check_migrations    raise TimeoutError(TimeoutError: There are still unapplied migrations after 60 seconds. MigrationHead(s) in DB: set() | Migration Head(s) in Source Code: {'405de8318b3a'}
```

I also tried to disable the waitForMigrations from the value.yaml, but ending up receiving this error.

```bash
[2024-03-12T07:41:20.611+0000] {configuration.py:2066} INFO - Creating new FAB webserver config file in: /opt/airflow/webserver_config.pyERROR: You need to initialize the database. Please run `airflow db init`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.7.1.
```

Questions are:

1. What is the usage of the migration, is it a must if I have a persistent RDS DB?
2. Where and How should I run this command `airflow db init`?
3. Anything else I can tweak my value.yaml to get the airflow up and running?

Comment: pls see this possible related issue that I ran into  https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/27992
applying the following workaround helped me:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/27992#discussioncomment-4584447

Answer (score 0):

I am running my deployment with Argo CD, and this comment from the official document helps to suppress the error for now.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html#installing-the-chart-with-argo-cd-flux-rancher-or-terraform

Installing the Chart with Argo CD, Flux, Rancher or Terraform
When installing the chart using Argo CD, Flux, Rancher or Terraform, you MUST set the four following values, or your application will not start as the migrations will not be run:

```yaml
createUserJob:
  useHelmHooks: false
  applyCustomEnv: false
migrateDatabaseJob:
  useHelmHooks: false
  applyCustomEnv: false
```